# Docusign Add Integrator Key

Tags: docusignapi

Do we need an Integrator Key for Developer Sandbox? If yes, I don't find an "Add Integrator Key" button under `Go to Admin -> API and Keys`.

Kindly advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there's currently a bug in the system which makes it so the button doesn't show, should be fixed very soon.  As a workaround you should be able to switch to the Classic UI and create your integrator key through there.

Go to Preferences menu -> Switch to Classic then once in the classic view once again go to Preferences menu in top right and select API screen in bottom left.  Then create your key.  Let me know if that doesn't work (post a comment).